# Powershell Regex Multiline parsing

Tags: powershell

I am working on building a script that will analyze a configuration file (cisco switch config) and build a report based on certain findings. Sadly- the findings must be recorded on a specific form so this painful path is my only option outside of manual generation of each form.

What I'm trying to do:
Using the following I am attempting to pull the following multi-line expression into PS for evaluation

```
interface vlan1
no ip address
shutdown
!
```

I have found multiple sources that point towards one of two options- the first (and simplest) being to load the file into Get-content using the "-raw" switch in order to evaluate the entire file as a single string and then use the "select-string" command to output the specific information that I am looking for.

My basic code looks something like this

```
if (get-content -path U:\Testing\Test.txt -Raw | select-string -Pattern "(?ms)interface vlan1.*no ip address.*(?!no shutdown)shutdown.*\!" -Quiet)
{
write-host('pass')
}
else
{
write-host('fail')
}
```

Expected outcome: if the string is true- I will append the finding to a file (that part I have already)

If the configuration does not contain "shutdown" exclusively (without the word no) then it will be annotated as such (again I have that process as well)

Thank you in advance for your assistance- hopefully this is clear and concise.

Further clarity: the script returns false positives/negatives. when running the get-content + select-string outside of the if command- I basically get the -raw output but no match on the string itself, leading me to believe that I am having an issue with the start of line (interface vlan1) and the end line (!)

I have played with the structure of the regex string to try and tease out a solution but I am still a bit vague as to the usage of multi-line output while using select-string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Since you need to look at the file *in full*, there's no reason to use the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) *cmdlet*, given that [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match), the regular-expression matching *operator*, works more effectively on strings that are already in memory.

  - Note: `-match` only every finds *one* match (if any); if this is not sufficient, use the [`[regex]::Matches()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches) .NET *method*; it is unfortunate that there's no *operator* for multiple matches; [GitHub issue #7867](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7867) proposes introducing one, named `-matchall`.
- Your regex is *too permissive* (greedy) due to use of `.*` *across lines* due to the `(?s)` matching option, so matching happens *across multiple blocks*.

The following uses a regex without `.*`, and instead explicitly matches the lines in full, including explicit matching of intervening newlines (`\r?\n`).<sup>[1]</sup>

This works with your sample input, but you may need to tweak the regex (omitting the `(?s)` option makes `.*` match only *intra*-line; expressions can be made *non-greedy* by modifying a duplication symbol with `?` (e.g. `.*?`)).

```sh
$re = '(?m)^interface vlan1\r?\nno ip address\r?\n(?!no shutdown)shutdown\r?\n!'
if ((Get-Content U:\Testing\Test.txt -Raw) -match $re) {
 # ... 
}
```

Note: The assumption is that there's no need to validate that the trailing `!` is the only character on its line; if that is needed, append `(?:\r?\n|\z)`.<sup>[2]</sup>

---

<sup>[1] This regex matches both common newline formats: CRLF (`\r\n`, Windows) and LF (`\n`, Unix).</sup>

<sup>[2] Unfortunately, use of `$` to assert the end of a line (with the `(?m)` option in effect) *may not work* if the input uses *CRLF* (`\r\n`) newlines, because the `$` matches the position of a LF character (`\n`) only, which means that `$` does *not* match immediately after `!`, due to the intervening `\r`.</sup>

Comment: Good catch, @SteveMartin - the `$` only works with LF-only newlines - please see my update.